# JBoss - EntityManager Injection Failed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, ejb

I want to use container  managed transaction in one class and share it with its subclasses.

Here is my abstract class :

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public abstract class AbstractDAO {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myDS")
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    protected SessionContext context;

    protected Logger log;

    public AbstractDAO() {
        log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

One of its child :

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class OrdreDAO extends AbstractDAO {
    public OrdreDAO() {

    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void persist(Ordre o) {
        em.persist(o);// NPE here ... no EntityManager injected !
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Ordre> findAll() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("from Ordre");
        return q.getResultList();
    }
}
```

On top of this child , OrdreService :

```
public class OrdreService {
    private OrdreDAO dao;

    public OrdreService() {
                dao=new OrdreDAO();
    }

    public void persist(Ordre o) {
        System.out.println("Service::persist  ??");
        dao.persist(o);
    }

    public List<Ordre> getOrdres() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    public Ordre getOrdre(String id) {
        return dao.findByPK(id);
    }

    public Ordre merge(Ordre o) {
        return dao.merge(o);
    }
}
```

A servlet using it :

```
public class creerOrdre extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private OrdreService os;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println("création ordre");
            Ordre o = new Ordre();
            o.setDate(req.getParameter("date"));
            o.setMotif(req.getParameter("motif"));

            System.out.println("Ordre: " + o.getDate() + " " + o.getMotif());

                            OrdreService os = new OrdreService()
            if (os!=null) {
                System.out.println("NON null !");   
            }
            os.persist(o);

            resp.sendRedirect("visualiser.jsp");
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            throw new ServletException(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

I get a NPE when I try to persist an `Ordre`
What am I missing ?

**JDK 6**
**JBoss 5.1.0.GA**
**JPA 1**

Comment: Why would you give a @Stateless on an abstract class ? You can remove it from there and test

Comment: I am unsure why your code doesn't work. What I can tell you is that NetBeans generates service facade classes exactly like you did, with the only difference that the EntityManager is injected in the subclass. And it works (at least on GlassFish 3). http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-generate-simpler-rest

Comment: I have updated my post with my some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OrdreService` `POJO` class is not managed by the web container, and also it seems to me that it's a useless additional layer. I would use only the `OrdreDAO`.

Anyway if you want to keep both classes, make `OrdreService` a `Stateless` `EJB`. Inject in `OrdreService` the `OrdreDAO` instance using:

```
@EJB private OrdreDAO dao;
```

Finally, inject `OrdreService` in your servlet using:

```
@EJB private OrdreService os;
```

This should work.